# Generalized Eigenvectors and Nilpotent Operators, Operators on Complex Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T ∈ L(V)$. Let $n=dim V$. Prove that:

range $T^n$= range T^(n+1)= range T^(n+2)=...

Can you use the fact that when n=dim V there is a direct sum of Range T^n and Null T^n?

Comment: You are getting good answers, but the recommended way of asking here is to include at least some of your own thoughts. Otherwise you give the impression that you want somebody to do your homework, and attract votes to close, and get a bad reputation that will hurt you in the long run here. If you don't know how to do that, may I suggest that you describe what happens when $V$ is one-dimensional? There are essentially only two cases there, so shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show this in two steps.

First, show that if range$T^m$ = range$T^{m+1}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ then range$T^{m+1}$ = range$T^{m+2}$ and hence 
range$T^m$ = range$T^{k}$ for all $k \geq m$ by induction.

Now, have a look at the sequence $V \supseteq \text{range}T \supseteq \text{range}T^2 \supseteq \dots$ and use $n = \text{dim}V$  to show that there exists $m \leq n$ such that range$T^m$ = range$T^{m+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a monotonic nonincreasing sequence of integers $d_0\ge d_1\ge d_2\ge\cdots$ all of which are nonnegative such that if $d_i=d_{i+1}$ then $d_i=d_j$ for all $i\le j$. See if you can use this information alone to prove that $d_n=d_{n+1}$, where $n=d_0$. Apply with $d_i:=\dim{\rm rng}(T^i)$.